# Emacs gnus isn't showing my mail group(s)

Tags: emacs, gnus

The only group in the *group* buffer is `9: nndoc+gnus-help:gnus-help`

My configuration is as follows:

```
(setq gnus-ignored-newsgroups "")
(setq user-mail-address "")
(setq user-full-name "Anthony Simpson")

(setq mail-sources 
      '((pop :server "pop.googlemail.com"
             :user ""
             :password ""
             :port 995
             :connection ssl
             :leave t)))

(setq gnus-select-method '(nnml ""))
```

Personal information removed, of course. Am I missing something? This appears to be the typical basic configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>A-A</kbd> from the group buffer to fetch and display all of the known groups? If that doesn't show your mail folders, then there is assuredly something amiss in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *subscribe* to your Gmail *inbox*.

In the Gnus groups buffer press <kbd>U</kbd> and type `INBOX`. You could press <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> to show all available groups you can subscribe to.

There is also a section on the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail#toc3) showing you how to change the groups regexp to allow the different Gmail folders.

Comment: The INBOX group doesn't even exist.